# Show in listview url image from database firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to pass different elementes from my database firebase, I want to show one URL image in the listView, for now I have this to show the text, but I don't know how to show the image.

Here is my Show code:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
Button btnDelete;
Module module;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_data);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Eventos");
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewShow);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBorrarElemento);
    //module=((Module)getApplicationContext());
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Eventos.class).toString();
            arrayList.add(value);
            Collections.reverse(arrayList);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

And here I have my module:

[image]

And I pass the string:

[image]

This is my database in firebase:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to get the image you will need to get the data from the event you want to pull the photo.

Steps

1. Create a reference to Eventos - eventId

   ex: mDatabaseRef.child("Eventos").child(eventId)
2. Get the event data with `.addValueEventListener` or `.addSingleValueForEventListener`
3. After you get URL (I think that this is the photoUrl you want to show) use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load that image in your desired ImageView